# How to get JSON from django HttpResponse?

Tags: python, django, json, httpresponse

I'm trying to get json objects from django HttpResponse. Actually access 'form_validation' value. But I can't. Any advice?

Here is my HttpResponse

```
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'response_data':response_data, 'form_validation':form_validation, 'guest': guest, 'error_list':error_array}), mimetype="application/json")
```

Comment: *How* are you trying to get the JSON objects? What do you receive on that side?

Comment: HttpResponse looks good, what's the Request look like?

Comment: I want to use 'form_validation' in a different function actually. How can I get?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `success` function for your ajax call which will have the json response object:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'},
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(response) {
            var response_data = response.response_data;
            var form_validation = response.form_validation;
            // access other fields
        },
        error: function(rs, e) {
            alert(rs.responseText);
        }
});
```